# In mysql table,i can't change discriminator value

Tags: grails, inheritance, mapping, discriminator

In grails, I have three classes like:

1.

```
package com.p1
class Node {
    static constraints = {
        name(blank:false,nullable:true)
    }
    String name
    static mapping = {
        discriminator column:"Node_Type"
    }
    String toString() {
        "$name"
    }
}
```

2.

```
package com.p1
class Task extends Node {
    static constraints = {
    }   
    static mapping =  {
        discriminator value:"TASK_NODE"
   }
}
```

3.

```
package com.p1
class Decision extends Node{
    static constraints = {
        assignee(nullable:true)
    }
    String assignee
     static mapping =  {
         discriminator value:"DECISION_NODE"
    }

}
```

In MySQL table, I can get the discriminator column name as `Node_Type`, **but I can't get the column value** like `TASK_NODE` and `DECISION_NODE`.

Instead, I am getting like this [`com.p1.Task` or `com.p1.Decision`]